# Как удалить active у всех кроме нажатой

Tags: javascript, html

Я новичок в js, поэтому вопрос возможно простейший. Подскажите как решить

```js
const menuBarBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-nav]'),
      menuBarTarget = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');

menuBarBtn.forEach(el => {
  el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      let index = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-nav');
      let target = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${index}"]`);
      if (target.classList.contains('active')) {
        
      } else {
        target.classList.add('active');
      }
  });
});
```

```css
[data-page].active {
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item3">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-page="item1">Item 1</div>
<div data-page="item2">Item 2</div>
<div data-page="item3">Item 3</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот пример кода как можно это сделать:

```js
const menuBarBtn = document.querySelectorAll('[data-nav]'),
menuBarTarget = document.querySelectorAll('[data-page]');

menuBarBtn.forEach(el => {
    el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
        let index = e.currentTarget.getAttribute('data-nav');
        let target = document.querySelector(`[data-page="${index}"]`);
        if (target.classList.contains('active')) {
            // Удалит выделение при повторном клике на выделенном
            // элементе
            target.classList.remove('active');
        } else {
                // Удалит выделение с ранее выделенных элементов
            for (let item of menuBarTarget){
                if (item.classList.contains('active'))
                    item.classList.remove('active');
            }
                
            target.classList.add('active');
        }
    });
});
```

```css
[data-page].active {
   background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item1">Item 1</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item2">Item 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a data-nav="item3">Item 3</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-page="item1">Item 1</div>
<div data-page="item2">Item 2</div>
<div data-page="item3">Item 3</div>
```